# Django - removing records and files from application by 'DELETE' method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following problem with my project in django 2.0.3. My application is based on the following model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class InputSignal(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adnotations = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I wanted to develop a mechanism to display rows contained in this database, and to delete individual records by 'DELETE' method. That's why I created this view function:

**views.py**

```
def storage_list(request):

    signals = InputSignal.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':

        id = json.loads(request.body)['id']
        signal = get_object_or_404(InputSignal, id=id)
        signal.delete()

        return HttpResponse('')

    else:

        return render(request, 'storage_list.html', {'signals': signals})
```

and following template:

**storage.html**

```
<ul>
{% for signal in signals %}
<li>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>{{ signal.name }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h6>Adnotations:</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>{{ signal.adnotations | safe  | linebreaks | truncatewords:16 }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button data-id="{{ signal.id }}" onclick='delteSignal(this)' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Which uses this js. script:

**script.js**

```
function delteSignal(e){

  let id = e.dataset.id
  e.closest('li').remove()

  fetch('', {
    method: 'DELETE',

    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
      'id': id
    }),

    credentials: 'same-origin',

  })
}
```

As a result of the operation of the presented code, the records seem to be removed from the database. Despite this, the files placed on the server using the FileField () field of the model stay in the / media / folder. What changes do I have to make to delete records from the database and files at the same time using the solution that I already implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to overwrite the `delete()` method in your model:

```
class InputSignal(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adnotations = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def delete(self):
        # Delete your files here + other things if needed
        self.input_file.delete()
        super().delete()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete) of the doc.